# Summing a row from a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want check if the row two in the list match with the input from the user.

For an example if the row two is following: `1 1 3`

And the user type in `5`

It shall say reply that the user typed in right answer.

The list is done, but I'm stuck now

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 3;
    int[,] z = new int[x, y];

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            z[i, j] = r.Next(0, 3);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            if (i == 3 && j == 3)
            {
                Console.Write("  ");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (z[i, j] > 9)
                    Console.Write(z[i, j] + " ");
                else
                    Console.Write(z[i, j] + "  ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine("Write the summing on row two ");
    int matain = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: So you don't know how to compare the value you got as input with the sum of 3 values in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sum = z[1,0] + z[1,1] + z[1,2];

if (matain == sum)
  Console.WriteLine("Correct");
else
  Console.WriteLine("Fail");

Console.ReadKey();
```